# Got a strange email

Tags: translation

I got a strange email entry that appears as follows:

[image]

What does it say?

Comment: paste into online dictionaries: 货到付款  ________   仅２９８元, 录像笔、摄像笔、录像笔-隐蔽摄像、夜视、移动侦测（摄像＋录音＋拍照＋DV...

Comment: ignore it. It is a spam trying to sell you some private-eyes equipment

Comment: @user6065 Actually Google translate is better for whole sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says

The left side:COD - Cash on Delivery

The right side: Only $298, Video Recording Pen, Stealth camera, night-vision, movement detection (Video recording + voice recording + take photo + DV...)